# Proximity Alert Intent not putting or returning extras

Tags: java, android, android-intent, gps, broadcastreceiver

What I'm doing is adding different proximity alerts with a unique ID as an extra and it's not working -

```
        for (int i = 0; i < latArray.size(); i++) 
    {   

        Bundle extra = new Bundle();
        extra.putInt("UID", i);
        Intent intent = new Intent(IntentToFire);  
        intent.putExtra("Blob", extra);
        PendingIntent proximityIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,-1 , intent, 0);
        LocationManager locationManager = 

        Log.i("Picture:","Location img:"+GetLocation.imgArray.get(i));
        Log.i("Potatoo:", "Lat :"+latArray.get(i)+" Lng :"+lngArray.get(i));
        locationManager.addProximityAlert(Double.valueOf(latArray.get(i)), Double.valueOf(lngArray.get(i)), radius,expiration,proximityIntent);
    }
```

And then on the broadcast receiver I'm putting this code -

```
flag = intent.getBundleExtra("blob").getInt("UID");
```

Every time I got to print flag, I just get an error. An ideas?

Comment: It basically says it doesn't exist. I used flag with an array and got a Null Pointer Exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use the FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT:

`PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,-1 , intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);`

I found it easiest is to encode data in the data-uri with proximity alerts on the `Intent` that is included in the pending intent, e.x.:

`geo:<lat>,<lon>?id=<your id>`

You can use your own protocol part though (`geo` is used by google maps AFAIK). No caching problems for me (seems you get a cached/old/wrong PendingIntent).